# UIImageView retains the Storyboard "preview screen bounds" on different devices - Frame not updating based on screen size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

When I run my app in simulator, the height and weight still get for my storyboard preview choose phone.

Should not be choose which kind of simulator?

ex:
storyboard preview choose iPhoneSE then the image view

weight = 96

height = 92

storyboard preview choose iPhone8 then the image view

weight = 112.5

height = 108.5

but when I storyboard preview choose iPhoneSE and simulator no matter choose which like iPhone 8, iPhoneX...

weight = 96

height = 92

Why?

Most weird thing is the same simulator when I choose different storyboard preview, I get different size...

```
print(self.img.frame.height)
print(self.img.frame.width)
```

Comment: Did you constraint the image view ?

Comment: It in a  stake view and the stake view equal height.

Comment: And do you have constraints on the UIStackView from the parent view?

Comment: All of my stake view constraints by equal height multiplier by super.height. My other ui unit are normal like button label. Only the image view be affected with storyboard view as.

Comment: I am having the same issue. 'View As' in the Storyboard in Xcode is affecting the size of the view when built. This is happening in the simulator as well as on device. I am looking into it and will let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution? @MattRundle

Comment: It's 2023 and this probably popped up unexpectedly on me. Never seen this before. Changing nothing by the preview device in storyboard causes incorrect constraints to be loaded in the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same issue, and I do not think it comes across well in the description above. To recreate it, take the following steps:

### Setup:

1) Start a new 'Single View App' in Xcode. I am currently using Xcode 10.2.1

2) Go into Storyboards and add a UIView object with some sort of backgroundColor so that it is visible

3) Give this new view some auto contraints, such as a leading, trailing, centerY, and an aspect ratio of 1:1. Just make sure to not give it a fixed height or width.

4) In `ViewController.swift`, add an IBOutlet variable such as 'myView' for this UIView and connect it so that it is easy to reference.

5) In `viewDidLoad()`, add a print statement to the effect of,

```
print("Bounds of myView: \(myView.bounds)")
```

### Testing the issue:

Now, back in Interface Builder, set the preview, or 'View as' at the bottom to something like 'iPhone SE'. Then, at the top, where you choose the simulator, also choose 'iPhone SE'. Now run the app.

In the console, you will see your print statement with the bounds of the view, and everything will look fine visually.

Now, change the Interface Builder's preview 'View as' option to something like 'iPhone 8', **but keep the simulator option on iPhone SE**
Again, run the app in the 'iPhone SE' simulator.

Just like before, visually everything is okay thanks to autolayout. However, the bounds information printed in the console is *different*. This instead matches the 'iPhone 8', or whatever device was chosen for preview in Interface Builder.

For an even more obvious example, choose something like an iPad Pro for the Interface Builder, and again run it on iPhone SE simulator. Again visually everything is okay, but the `bounds` information in the console is way off. It is tied to the Interface Preview and not to the device being tested.

The problems arise when you are writing code which uses the bounds information of an object under autolayout constraints which do not have a fixed width and height.

### Solution:

In `ViewController.swift`, add the following after the `viewDidLoad()` method

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    print("Bounds of myView in viewDidLayoutSubviews: \(myView.bounds)")
  }
```

Now, no matter what preview option we use in Interface Builder, the simulator logs the correct bounds information at this point in the lifecycle.

So, for any projects which make use of the `bounds` or `frame` property in code for such a view as the one in this example, should place any code refrencing that bounds within the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method.

Comment: this solution is doing nothing, you are just overriding a superview method and just making a print statement in it, this is actually the point where your views gets  their actual bounds.

Comment: Yes. That is the point I am making to the person who asked the question. If they want to access the actual computed bounds of the view, they need to do it within `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and not `viewDidLoad()`. The println statements are just there so they can see the proof.

Answer (score 1):

if you added the `leading, trailing, top and bottom` constraints you will get different size of the imageView on different screen sizes and if you want the imageView to have a fixed size on every screen then you can use `centerX` and `centerY` constraints for positioning and add constant width and height

> Example 1

[image: image with adjustable width and height]

> Example 2

adding imageView width and height

[image]

adding centerX and centerY constraints

[image]

> Explanation

in `Example 1` image width and height will be dynamic and in `Example 2` height and width of the imageView will be same no matter which device is used to display

Comment: My problem is why storyboard view as choose different preview the view can effect really choose simulator

Comment: I run my app at iPhone 8 simulator but storyboard view as not iPhone 8 then image view width and height will be storyboard view as. I am very confuse, if I build ipa what will happen?  according to storyboard choose view as at building?

Comment: storyboard preview shows how your application will actually look on  different simulators. By using this feature we do not need to run our application on multiple simulators to see how the actually looks on different devices we can do that by simply changing the preview device in Interface Builder

Comment: The preview device will effect the real run simulator. If I preview by iPhone 6 or 8 and run at iPhone 8 will be different...

Comment: I am in IOS development for more than a year but never faced anything like thing, it sounds illogical to me

Comment: I also think so. I will change mac and check that. Thank all of you.